# Manually Building a Tree in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, tree

I'm currently working on building an application in CakePHP.  There's a quite extensive existing data set that's conceptually a tree, but wasn't previously stored as one.  What I mean by that, is there's no real relationship defined in the data.

The problem I'm having is getting it to work correctly with the CakePHP tree behaviour.  Because I have to set all the values on existing data - as opposed to Cake setting up the structure as elements are inserted - I need to understand how the lft/rght values work.

So, I guess the question is:

How does the structure data work, specifically the lft/rght values?  How do I set it up so that the data comes out rationally, without inserting them one at a time?  It's a 2 level tree, with Sections and sub-sections.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The MPTT tree logic is rather simple and well explained in [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). In summary, every entry has a left and a right value. Every entry whos left/right values are within another entries left-right range are a descendent of that (latter) element. E.g. the LCD node (5/6) is within the range of its parent node, Televisions (2-9).

[image]
<sub>(source: [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data-4.png))</sub>

To build the lft/rght values for a "new" tree just set all the `parent_ids` properly and run [`$this->Model->recover()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/790/Data-Integrity) on it. Cake will calculate the lft/rght values for you.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was able to figure out how the left/right values worked last night, but I really wish I'd found the recover method before I set them all manually...

Comment: Luckily I *did* just find this post before I tried to manually set them :)